# LogisticRegression on binary-class problem: does not predict the class

Tags: logistic, scikit-learn

I tried to use sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression() on data where the labels are 0 or 1.

```
classifier.fit(points, labels)
classifier.predict(points)
```

The output of predict() is just float numbers, not 0 or 1. How can I use these numbers to predict the class? Earlier I used LogisticRegression on a multi-class problem and it worked like expected: predict() gave a list of class labels.

Here are some of the numbers to give an idea what kind of values are returned

```
| Ground truth | Predicted         |
| 0            | -0.111150306239   |
| 0            | -0.0512831764939  |
| 0            | -0.013679188285   |
| 0            | 0.0352547833906   |
| 0            | -0.11803991099    |
| 0            | -0.0229271929814  |
| 0            | -0.00503382920251 |
| 1            | 0.171778695897    |
| 1            | 0.172446438354    |
| 1            | 0.171671273603    |
| 1            | 0.171080529438    |
| 1            | 0.172126091075    |
| 1            | 0.173032701832    |
```

Furthermore, I tried LinearRegression.predict_proba() just to see what it would return but I get `AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you initialize your classifier ? It seems like you initialized a Linear Regression model instead of a logistic regression.

Comment: Well this is embararssing... That was the case, and somehow I did not consider the possibility. Thank you.